# Change logo that appears in Android ActionBar programatically

Tags: android, image, icons, tablet, android-actionbar

Is there a way to change the logo that appears in the `ActionBar` inside an `Activity` instead of listing it in the Manifest?

The reason I ask is I have an app for phones where I build a similar type of bar across the top with the launcher icon in the left corner similar to the `ActionBar` using an `ImageView`.

I also allow the user to change that image to one on their phone or on the internet.  I am currently making the app work for tablets and would like to just use the `ActionBar` instead but can't figure out how to change the image based on the user.  There is no method in the `ActionBar` class and I could not find a way to modify the icon or logo from the resources.

Anyone know if this is possible or could suggest something I could try?

Answer (score 12):

Prior to the introduction in API 14 of the `setIcon` and `setLogo` methods that Jake mentions, you appear to be able to change the ActionBar logo by grabbing the view of `android.R.id.home` and setting a new drawable.

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
logo.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 10):

API 14 introduced [`setIcon`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon(int)) and [`setLogo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setLogo(int)) methods.

As for 11 through 13 there's no *easy* way.

You could possibly use a custom navigation and hide the regular icon/logo by having your own layout mimic its functionality.

There is a `homeLayout` attribute in the action bar style which allows specifying an alternate layout resource to be used but it will always throw a `ClassCastException` since it is instantly cast to an internal class upon inflation ([bug #21842](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21842)).

Comment: That attribute wasn't intended to be made public. Oops. :)