# Custom image instead of logo in ActionBar/ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, image, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, graphical-logo

How can I change the default logo icon of an ActionBar to be a custom image? Similar as how it works on Whatsapp? [image: Whatsapp custom image as logo]

Comment: did you find solution.. i have same requirment.. thanks in advance

Comment: I solved my problem by providing a custom view for the ActionBar. Take a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The ActionBar uses the [android:logo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#logo) attribute of your manifest, if one is provided.  That lets you use separate drawable resources for the icon (Launcher) and the logo (ActionBar, among other things).*

---

So you should add this tag into manifest like ..

```
<application
    android:logo="@drawable/custom_image"
```

***Update :***

You can use `ActionBar.setLogo()` for runtime. Two versions are there [setLogo(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setLogo%28int%29) and [setLogo(Drawable logo)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setLogo%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Read [Define custom Logo for ActionBar (different than Logo) in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728365/define-custom-logo-for-actionbar-different-than-logo-in-xml) which will help you to define some styles also.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. The problem is that I want to set a custom image to that icon. In whatsapp that image is a friend's profile picture (it is specified at runtime).

Comment: you can use `ActionBar.setIcon(Drawable)`

Comment: @carlos .. did you find solution.. i have same requirment.. thanks in advance

Comment: Its not working and I don't know why. I have tried everything

Comment: @FaizanMubasher What is not working? Can you ask one separate question with your code please?

Comment: Actually! I can't ask separate question as that gonna be definitely negative ;-) . I have tried all things that mentioned here and also tried other threads. I don't know where I am getting wrong.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Hey I am sorry :( without code I can not help you. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

The simplest technique is to use setIcon(R.drawable.icon_name) Similarly you can do with the Title and you can also set the date in the action bar subtitle.

```
ActionBar ab= getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("Aries");
ab.setSubtitle(dateFormat.format(date));
ab.setIcon(R.drawable.aries3d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the ActionBarSherlock. Include an xml called "styles_mytheme.xml" in values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/overflow_selector</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/overflow_selector</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomActionOverflowDropDownText</item>
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomTitleColorBar</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_nav_home_back</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_nav_back</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_nav_home_back</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownStyles</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownStyles</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">

        <!-- define background for action bar (sets default for all parts of action bar - main, stacked, split) -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/navigation</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/navigation</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style for the color title bar -->
    <style name="CustomTitleColorBar" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionOverflowDropDownText" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My_Theme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenuStyle</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenuStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyApp.PopupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/navigation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownStyles" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/overflow_selector</item>


    </style>

</resources>
```

Now include this xml in the code:

```
setTheme(Theme.Styled);
```

Now change these three lines, when you change these three lines, the icon will change:

```
  <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_nav_home_back</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_nav_back</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_nav_home_back</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.add_contact);
    }
```