# Android Action Bar: Can I replace a custom Title in appcompat v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I want to add a custom action title on the left of the actin bar, replacing with the default title just like in the below image the default image is shown

[image]

And here I want to add this title.

[image]

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19172556

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Comment: u can create custom layout and set to action bar

Comment: @Naser we can't use custom layout, because we have to add a buuton for sorting in its child fragment.

Comment: the image you have shown is of navigation drawer. On click of it the sliding menu will open up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the logo and the title in action bar.

You can use

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("your title");
```

and

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setLogo(your draw id);
```

Comment: you use this answer? it helps you? if yes, pls approve them

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to do ..

There's lot's of way to do this task as defined above .. but I will suggest to make use of custom view for Action bar(**As this will work on all devices as same**) .. this will let you create much more complex view's in a very handy and easy way.

For your query you make make use of custom views for ActionBar..

You can create customized action bar like this ..

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.xyz); // Set custom view like this 
// In your case you want an icon ... 
ImageView image = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.fare_ll); // Get id of custom view like this
```

Also you need to set this property ..

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

// Now you can do any sort of stuffs with this icon .. like you can perform click functionality
```

Here's your xyz.xml file .. This file is just for your reference purpose .. this will let you know how to create custom view for Action Bar. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

     >

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"
        android:id="@+id/confirm_cabs_back"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/b"
            />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:id="@+id/city_spinner_layout"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/action_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XYZ"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/taxi_blue"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <!-- <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/drop_down" /> -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

     <!-- <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="end|center"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:id="@+id/fare_ll"
         > -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey" >
    </LinearLayout> 
     <!-- android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hard_61"
        android:id="@+id/fare_ll"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"

        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
   <!--  </LinearLayout> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

You are good to go ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following code to get this:

```
private ActionBar actionBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo); //logo needs to be defined in the drawables folder.
}
```