# Custom big logo in actionbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I implement such big logo in actionbar? Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: try ActionBar#setCustomView

Comment: @vokilam unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActionBar.setLogo()` for runtime. Two versions are there `setLogo(int resId)` and `setLogo(Drawable logo)`.

Read [Define custom Logo for ActionBar (different than Logo) in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728365/define-custom-logo-for-actionbar-different-than-logo-in-xml) which will help you to define some styles also.

Comment: Actually this is not what I want. It sets small (!) logo but not big.

Comment: create a bigger image and then set as drawable using ActionBar.setLogo(Drawable logo)