# Android ActionBar logo doesn't display

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I implemented a theme for my ActionBar:

```
<style name="MyTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="logo">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

And I applied it in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
...
```

I know that my theme works as I see a color change, however my actionbar icon never shows up. I see it only when I explicitly call this code in `onCreate` method of my activity:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

I feel like it's not correct to copy-paste the same code for every activity. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you running on lollipop?

Comment: @Johan yes, that's right

Comment: Well, lollipop (read Material) doesn't show icons in the `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`, its part of their design guides.

Comment: You should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8729587/3743245 btw, try to use a Icon (setIcon)... Logos doesn't go well with Material Design (with a simple Title should work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new compat library doesn't use logos nor app icons in the Toolbar (former ActionBar). You should check the style guides about that: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars

Starting with lollipop you get new features like tinting the notification bar on this screen:

[image]

A cool new feature is that tinting which can color all ui elements like you need it for your branding.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` , you can setup your app's action bar as follows:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.apptoolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_app_logo);
```

for more info you can read at [Structure Of App Bar](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)(which was called as ActionBar)